# Does Jekyll read *every* post+meta before generating a site?

Tags: jekyll, static-site

I'm currently tinkering with various Static Site Generators (Jekyll, Hugo, Pelican), and wondering about the methods they use for gather site-wide data.

In Jekyll's case, there is `site.posts`, which contains data for all posts in the site (for building index pages, etc. I'm wondering about the inner workings.

**Is Jekyll holding all of the site content + metadata in memory during building the site?**

The naive way I'm imagining this seems very inefficient, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a better, more "asynchronous" methods. How else would `site.posts` be populated and available for all generated pages?

**Do you have any "small" examples or insight into how Jekyll tackles this problem, specifically?**